# Is there any background information for the Firebase Object Detector?

Tags: android, firebase, machine-learning, computer-vision

I recently saw the Google I/O talk about the Firebase Object Detector, which works on the device. I implemented it based on [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/android/detect-objects) and [this](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/mlkit-android-odt/index.html?index=..%2F..index#5) link. It works, but I want to know if there is any background information for the used detector. is it some sort of neural network? If yes, then which kind and on what training set and what categories was it trained? If it isn't a neural network, then what kind ob CV algorithm is used?
Any background information would help me very much!